# Elegant way to count number of elements in each column of a matrix that are greater than those in every other column?

Tags: r, matrix, linear-programming

I currently have a solution that works. I'm wondering if there is a more elegant approach?

First the setup:

```
set.seed(315)
mat <- matrix(sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE), nrow = 4, ncol = 5)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    4    1    3    3
[2,]    5    3    5    1    4
[3,]    4    1    1    4    3
[4,]    3    3    1    1    1
```

From this matrix, I want to create an 5x5 output matrix, where the entry in *i,j* is the number of elements in **column** *j* that were greater than **column** *i* of the input matrix.

**edit**: Originally I described a solution where the entry *i,j* of the output solution is the number of elements in **column** *i* are greater than **column** *j*, but provided the opposite relationship in the output. I changed the description to match the output, and any differences in the answers provided are probably a result of that.

This solution gives the desired output:

```
mat.pm <- apply(mat, MARGIN = 2,
                function(x) {
                  return(apply(mat, MARGIN = 2, function(y) {
                    return(sum(x > y))
                  }))
                })

> mat.pm
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    0
[2,]    2    0    1    1    2
[3,]    3    2    0    2    2
[4,]    2    3    1    0    1
[5,]    3    2    1    1    0
```

Is there possibly a better way that doesn't involve double-nested apply functions?

**edit**: here is some benchmarking for the various approaches:

```
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(315)
bm_data <- matrix(sample(1:5, 6000, replace = TRUE), nrow = 200, ncol = 30)

op <- microbenchmark(
  APPLY1 = apply(bm_data, MARGIN = 2,
                function(x) {
                  return(apply(bm_data, MARGIN = 2, function(y) {
                    return(sum(x > y))
                  }))
                }),
  APPLY2 = apply(bm_data, 2 , function(x) colSums( x > bm_data)),
  SWEEP = apply(bm_data,2,function(x) colSums(sweep(bm_data,1,x,"-")<0)),
  VECTORIZE = {
    n <- 1:ncol(bm_data);
    ind <- expand.grid(n, n)
    out <- colSums(bm_data[,c(ind[,2])] > bm_data[,c(ind[,1])])
  },
  SAPPLY = sapply(seq(ncol(bm_data)), function(i) colSums(bm_data[, i] > bm_data)),
  times = 100L
)

> summary(op)
       expr      min        lq    median        uq       max neval
1    APPLY1 9742.091 10519.757 10923.896 11876.614 13006.850   100
2    APPLY2 1012.097  1080.926  1148.111  1247.965  3338.314   100
3     SWEEP 7020.979  7667.972  8580.420  8943.674 33601.336   100
4 VECTORIZE 3036.700  3266.815  3516.449  4476.769 28638.246   100
5    SAPPLY  978.812  1021.754  1078.461  1150.782  3303.798   100
```

@Ricardo's **SAPPLY** and @Simon's **APPLY2** strategies are both nice, one line solutions that perform much faster that my **APPLY1** approach. In terms of *elegance*, @Simon's update with **APPLY2** hits the mark - simple, readable and fast.

One takeaway I learned through discussion here is how much faster `apply` functions rip through a matrix compared to a `data.frame`. Convert, then compute if possible.

@Simon's `expand.grid` is the most creative - I had not even thought to approach the problem in that way. Nice.

Comment: FWIW your output matrix is essentially triangular, since the upper triangle is (row_length) - lower_triangle .  You might be able to reduce the process time by running a double for-loop `i in 1:n` and `j in 1:i` .  I'll wait to see what `R-magic` the experts come up with, perhaps combining `melt/cast` with `order`.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - that would be true if the formula counted cases "greater than or equal to", but it only counts cases that are "greater than." I am writing this for a package, so I want to accomplish this using base R - I'll update the question with that detail.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you are calling `i` and `j`, but I dont see how your output `mat.pm` matches with `"where the entry in i,j is the number of elements in column i that were greater than column j of the input matrix"`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta - you're right and you offer a nice solution too. I will update what I describe to match the provided output, but will make note of the change so differences in solutions make sense.

Comment: @christianlemp see my edit in my answer, but I think `apply( mat , 2 , function(x) colSums( x > mat )` will be the quickest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Edit:

See below for details but you can do this in a single `apply` loop:

```
apply( mat , 2 , function(x) colSums( x > mat )
```

`apply` is fast here, because is optimised to work on matrices. A lot of the time spent using `apply` is *usually* in the conversion of a `data.frame` to a matrix which is not needed here.

---

#### Original:

It's possible to do this entirely vectorised because `>` has an method for `matrices` and `data.frame`s. Therefore you can get the indices of columns to compare using `expand.grid()`, use this to subset the matrix, do the logical comparison and then use `colSums` to get the result and `matrix` to wrap it back up to the correct size. All this in 4 lines (really it could be 2):

```
n <- 1:ncol(mat)
ind <- expand.grid(n,n)
out <- colSums( mat[,c(ind[,1])] > mat[,c(ind[,2])] )
   
matrix( out , ncol(mat) , byrow = TRUE )
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    2    0    1    1    2
#[3,]    3    2    0    2    2
#[4,]    2    3    1    0    1
#[5,]    3    2    1    1    0
```

---

#### Update:

`apply` seems even faster, and combining `apply` with @Ricardo's comparison of the whole `matrix` leads us to a single, fastest (?) `apply` solution which is approximately 4 times quicker than the OP:

```
#  Single apply loop
f1 <- function(mat) apply( mat , 2 , function(x) colSums( x > mat ) )

#  OP double apply loop
f2 <- function(mat) {apply(mat, MARGIN = 2,
                function(x) {
                  return(apply(mat, MARGIN = 2, function(y) {
                    return(sum(x > y))
                  }))})}

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark( f1(mat) , f2(mat) )

#Unit: microseconds
#    expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# f1(mat)  95.190  97.6405 102.7145 111.4635  159.584   100
# f2(mat) 361.862 370.7860 398.7830 418.3810 1336.506   100
```

Comment: dang!  I knew there was `expand.grid` but couldn't remember the name, and `outer` definitely wasn't the way to go.

Comment: oh I like your updated solution a lot - one line and very speedy. I never realized the difference in speed computing on a matrix vs. `data.frame`, but the truth comes out when comparing the results.

Answer (score 4):

I think the results you have are transposed:

```
## This gives you what you show as output
sapply(seq(ncol(mat)), function(i) colSums(mat[, i] > mat))

## This gives you what you _describe_ in the question
t(sapply(seq(ncol(mat)), function(i) colSums(mat[, i] > mat)))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    2    3    2    3
[2,]    1    0    2    3    2
[3,]    0    1    0    1    1
[4,]    0    1    2    0    1
[5,]    0    2    2    1    0
```

Comment: +1 Nice result. One use of subsetting - I *should've* thought of that.

Comment: Thanks simon.  I like the expand.grid method as well

Comment: @RicardoSaporta - I added benchmarking to the question for the various approaches given. I'm not getting the same rank for median time as what you've posted here; why could that be?

Comment: @christianlemp, my apologies, I am not able to reproduce the results I had posted (and since removed) either.  I didn't save it, so I can't say for certain, but I am guessing my incorrect results were probably due to not having properly switched my variable from `mat` to `bigmat` when benchmarking the function (so it was probably grabbing the older, smaller var)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using only 1 `apply`, but replacing the other with `sweep`, so not sure it counts:

```
apply(mat,2,function(x) colSums(sweep(mat,1,x,"-")<0))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    0
[2,]    2    0    1    1    2
[3,]    3    2    0    2    2
[4,]    2    3    1    0    1
[5,]    3    2    1    1    0
```

Comment: +1 for introducing `sweep` (and for answering this in about two minutes). I didn't accept this answer though because using `microbenchmark` to compare results with 1000 runs, the `sweep` approach is about 6 times slower than using a double nested `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

Benchmarking:

```
 bigmat<-matrix(sample(0:5,200,rep=T),nr=10)
    gridfoo <- function(mat) {
    n <- 1:ncol(mat)
    ind <- expand.grid(n,n)
    out <- colSums( mat[,c(ind[,1])] > mat[,c(ind[,2])] )
    }

    appfoo<- function(mat) apply(mat,2,function(x) colSums(sweep(mat,1,x,"-")<0))


    app2foo<- function(mat) t(sapply(seq(ncol(mat)), function(i) colSums(mat[, i] > mat)))

 microbenchmark(gridfoo(bigmat),appfoo(bigmat),app2foo(bigmat),times=10)
Unit: microseconds
            expr      min       lq    median       uq      max neval
 gridfoo(bigmat)  363.909  369.895  381.4410  413.086  522.557    10
  appfoo(bigmat) 1208.892 1231.129 1238.1850 1252.083 1521.913    10
 app2foo(bigmat)  298.482  310.883  317.0835  323.284  762.454    10
```

But...(notice difference in time unit)

```
Rgames> bigmat<-matrix(sample(0:5,20000,rep=T),nr=100)
Rgames> microbenchmark(gridfoo(bigmat),appfoo(bigmat),app2foo(bigmat),times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
            expr       min        lq   median        uq       max neval
 gridfoo(bigmat) 106.15115 112.98458 149.5746 183.87987 249.35418    10
  appfoo(bigmat) 127.44553 127.92874 132.5372 136.42562 199.12123    10
 app2foo(bigmat)  14.64483  14.99676  18.6089  20.51824  20.91122    10
```

Comment: also, you should add a `t()` to `appfoo` and a `dim()` to `gridfoo` to get a better comparison. Right now, it fails on `identical(appfoo(bigmat), app2foo(bigmat))` etc

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it might not scale well because of the heavy merge step.

```
library(reshape2)
matmelted <- melt(mat)
matmeltedcross<- merge(matmelted,matmelted,by = 'Var1', allow.cartesian = TRUE)
matmeltedcross$count <- matmeltedcross$value.x > matmeltedcross$value.y
mat.pm <- with(
  matmeltedcross[matmeltedcross$count == TRUE,],
  table(Var2.y,Var2.x)
)
```

Output -

```
> mat.pm
      Var2.x
Var2.y 1 2 3 4 5
     1 0 1 0 0 0
     2 2 0 1 1 2
     3 3 2 0 2 2
     4 2 3 1 0 1
     5 3 2 1 1 0
```